# How to get access to any context in app.js, out of the render function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am trying to get the login status in my ContextProvider in app.js which is the root of my application so it is not possible to get it with useContext. At least I could not manage to get it. I am planning to render different AppStack navigator stack based on the loginStatus, so I need to get the state in app.js. Do you know any way to work around this problem? 
This is my app.js file:

```
const App = props => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const _cacheResourcesAsync = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      "poppins-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
      "poppins-medium": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
      "poppins-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
      "segoe-ui": require("./assets/fonts/segoe-ui.ttf"),
      "Montserrat-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"),
      Dosis: require("./assets/fonts/Dosis.ttf"),
      "FjallaOne-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf"),
      "Lobster-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf")
    });
  };
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={_cacheResourcesAsync}
        onFinish={() => setIsLoading(false)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <ExperienceProvider>
        <AppProvider>
          <AppStack
            loginStatus={loginStatus}
            ref={navigatorRef => {
              NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
            }}
          />
        </AppProvider>
      </ExperienceProvider>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the  element in Provider can help .

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./styles/index.scss";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { LoginProvider } from "./context/loginContext.js";

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<LoginProvider>
  <App />
</LoginProvider>
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```